# Why the Akka actor prints after a stop instruction?

Tags: akka, actor

I'm now learning Akka and there is something I do not understand.

I've read that `context.stop(self)` stops the actor and ignores the rest of the messages in the queues. Is this true?

I have the following actor, which receives the "stop" message, prints "gonna stop" and then "I printed something but I'm not alive".
How is possible to print the second line? I thought that `context.stop(self)` would immediately stop the actor.

```
class Alice extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "stop" =>
      println("gonna stop")
      context.stop(self)
      println("I printed something but I'm not alive")
    // other cases
  }
```

Comment: Not knowing much of Akka, I would think that saying "stop" is not an exceptional case - hence, the current receive iteration will execute until the end and that's it for the actor.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this true?

Yes, that is true.

> How is possible to print the second line? I thought that `context.stop(self)` would immediately stop the actor.

The `stop` method will stop the actor from processing any further messages that are in the actor's inbox. But it doesn't immediately jump out of the method that is processing the current message. It lets the actor finish processing the current message, but after that no other messages will be processed.

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense. Thanks!